# htaccess rewrite if condition if variable is equal to a certain string

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using mod rewrite in an .htaccess file to change the URL to a nicer one, it converts this:

```
http://domain.com?a=test&v=page&id=3
```

to

```
http://domain.com/test/page/3
```

using this condition

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?a=$1&v=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

I want to do something different if $1 == cart and $2 == home

Here is some pseudo code for the idea using a php `if` condition

```
if($1 == 'cart' && $2 == 'home'){
   here I want to do a different rewrite rule
}else{
   RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?a=$1&v=$2&id=$3 [L]
}
```

Any idea as to how I go about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 rewrite rules, with the predefined one first:

```
RewriteRule ^cart/home/([^/\.]+)?$            page2.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$  index.php?a=$1&v=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^cart/home/([^/.]+)?$ other_page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Then continue with the rule you already have.